# Wrong SQL query (beginner)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new in SQL, and I am learning alone on Udemy. I came across multiple questions, and I am struggling with one of them:

What is wrong with this SQL query?

```
SELECT sport, count(*) 
FROM activities 
WHERE username IN ‘tony’
GROUP BY 1;
```

I have two hypothesis:
1 - If the field 'sport' in activities is filled with string values, then we can't use count.
2 - the last statement should be rather:

```
WHERE username in:‘tony’ GROUP BY 1;
```

I would be happy to have your feedback on the question and learn from you!
Thanks

Comment: "1 - If the field 'sport' in activities is filled with string values, then we can't use count." `count()` can be happily used on strings (and you're using `*` anyway). I guess you mixed `count()` up with `sum()`.

Comment: True, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

search IN will use with () round brackets

```
SELECT sport, count(*) 
FROM activities 
WHERE username IN ('tony')
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add parentheses for tony, 
example: if u  want to check for multiple names ('tony','stark')

```
SELECT sport, count(*) 
FROM activities 
WHERE username IN ('tony')
GROUP BY 1;
```